# Laravel 5.1: How to authenticate only active users

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to add another condition in `AuthController` but I don't know how to do it.

In my `Users` table, I have a `Active` field. If a `User` has `Active == 0`, i want to not let he/she login into the system. I don't know where to add that condition in Laravel 5.1 `AuthController`.

Please help me with that. 
Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `postLogin` method of the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in your `AuthController`:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{ 
    /* PLACE HERE VALIDATION CODE... */  

    //attempt login but not log in the user
    if ( ! Auth::attempt($credentials, false, false) )
    {
        //wrong credentials: redirect to login
    }   

    //CREDENTIALS OK

    //get user model from last attempt
    $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();

    //if user is not active... 
    if (! $user->active)
    {
        //do whathever you want: for example redirect to login    
    }

    //USER IS ACTIVE

    //login the user
    Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember')); 

    //redirect where you need
}
```

Check the original: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::postLogin` method, to see if you need other instructions inside your overrided method (for example input validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom postLogin() function in your Auth controller which overrides the default postLogin function  with this condition

```
Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1))
```

This way you will only do auth of active users only

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the whole postLogin function, add this to your **AuthController**

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $crendentials=$request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
    $crendentials['active']=1;
    return $crendentials;
}
```